# Which weapon can transfer more energy to a projectile: sling or slingshot?

Tags: projectile, rotational-kinematics, elasticity

Which weapon can transfer the most energy to a projectile, a [sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)) or [slingshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slingshot)?

Each is totally powered by a person, one stores energy in elastic the other kinetically. Which can store and transfer the most energy to a projectile?

For a fair comparison, limits are completely human powered and supported. No slingshots anchored to the ground. No [Trebuchets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet).

Comment: David swears by the sling, says it brings down giants.

Comment: I think physics SE guys would come up with a mcuh better answer with equations and reason. :)

Comment: on the net (forums, dedicated sites etc) slingshots delivered energy numbers go from 7-12J up all the way to the very particular one that detains the record. The difference in models, materials, people testing, testing methods (and applied math too) might account for the numbers all over the place. There is much less data for the sling, although some of those come from researchers that applied more reliable testing methods. A slingshot will kill a rat... slings were said to take down horses in battle... a sling projectile has a lot more mass too, its apples and oranges so YMMV

Answer (score 3):

Although there are physics involved, this is largely a physiology question.

A slingshot can impart as much energy to a projectile as the user can transfer to the bands. If we assume bands that are strong enough to withstand more stretching than any human can manage, it will depend entirely on his pulling strength.

Similarly, a sling can impart as much energy to a projectile as the user can transfer to the sling. But unlike a slingshot which uses linear acceleration, a sling uses angular momentum since slings are generally "fired" by spinning the sling rapidly and then releasing it with a final motion of the arm adding additional energy.

If we assume the user can impart the same amount of muscular force to either weapon and is equally skilled in using both, then the sling wins because that final motion of the arm is imparting energy to a projectile that is already in motion and therefore already has stored energy, while a slingshot is imparting the same amount of energy to a stationary projectile. Some of the energy the slingshot user can muster will have to be used just to accelerate the projectile from a standstill to the same speed the sling started out with.

Comment: This assumption cannot be correct: You can use quite a lot of force to pull on a slingshot, but on a sling it is not about force. You cannot apply much force. You continuously apply an increasing force needed to hold the projectile on a circular path while its accelerating. The acceleration comes from moving your hand such that you always pull just a little bit ahead of the circular motion, not perfectly perpendicular inward. So it is more of a question of how high a frequency you can maintain i.e. coordination.

Comment: @imsodin That's like saying a baseball pitcher can't apply much force to a circular windup, but we know they most certainly can. Yes, the circular motion provides the base level of velocity, and a huge amount of coordination is certainly required. I'm sure that achieving mastery with a sling is much more difficult than a slingshot, but once achieved a good arm can add a lot more acceleration with the final throw with a sling than a slingshot can achieve with the same strength and coordination.

Comment: Sorry I may not have been very clear in my expression: I do not doubt your conclusion (I know hardly anything about slings or baseball) just the part of your explanation where you state that you can apply the same muscular force into finally accelerating the particle. In a sling much energy comes from continuous acceleration. This is distinct from a baseball pitcher who has to accelerate in just one swing, so muscular force is much more important. Sure as always muscular force helps to coordination, but I guess core strength is just as important for slings as arm/shoulder strength.

Answer (score 1):

With my slingshot I can launch a 1/4" ball bearing maybe 60 yards.  With my sling I can launch a 1" ball bearing maybe 120 yards.  The science/engineering guys can give you a more precise answer, my experience says the sling imparts more energy by something like at least an order of magnitude.